# How to index portable hard disk (2.5")?

Tags: external-hard-drive

How to index my portable hard disk (2.5") ?  having lots of materials in the harddisk, searching becomes harder.  Is there a way that i can index my entire hard disk (for txt / pdf / html ) files and just search the content like a google desktop ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [**Everything**](http://voidtools.com/) from voidtools. It can index any **local or removable** NTFS volumes within seconds and searching is basically instantaneous:

[image]